# AS3 AIR Datagramsocket - how to know if target is recieving

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, networking, air

How can you know if the target is recieving data if you are using a datagramsocket (UDP)? Should you try to connect to it with socket (TCP) first?

Comment: You should not mix both protocols together. There are some good answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942574/datagramsocket-bind-and-connect-difference).

Comment: That did not really answer my question :/

Comment: And why should I not mix them?

Comment: [UDP vs TCP](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/udp-vs-tcp/): _Don’t mix TCP and UDP, instead learn how to implement the specific pieces of TCP that you wish to use inside your own custom UDP based protocol._

Comment: Then how should I implement the specific pieces of TCP that I wish to use inside my own custom UDP based protocol in as3?

Comment: Most of the details are followed in the tutorial I linked you to. It's all in C++ though, but the concepts are all the same regardless of the language. I personally haven't used AS3 Datagram Socket so unfortunately I can't help you with specific details.

Comment: Some of the comments in the link you gave me is making me a Little bit confused. They say that TCP is faster and so on... Is that correct? But thank you for the help :)

Comment: If anything TCP is much slower for real-time applications, but very reliable, and robust in terms of congestion. Where exactly did you read that TCP is faster?

Comment: Someone said this in the comment section: "5) in reality, TCP-packets usually are delivered EARLIER than datagrams – because they’re prioritized in every professional router / backbone, all of the ISPs all over the world do that; its an unwritten rule and can be seen in reality everday, even with the simplest of tools – this results in a better latency AND ping, although the difference is very small (usually .1 to 2 ms)."